which is best to use for solr heavy data ? solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory Vs solr.MMapDirectoryFactory?
We are planning to upgrade solr from 8.9 to 9.4 and I found some configuration exist in solr-8.9 and thinking to update some configuration for better performance.
After doing some troubleshooting some of thread suggesting to use NRTCachingDirectoryFactory instead of MMapDirectoryFactory in solr config.
To improve solr search performance, Which is best to use for heavy data around 76 million in production ?
Thanks in advance !
